# Vba macro if cell contains value, then input specific text on other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel document which has a lot of info and statistics and i am trying to figure out how to solve the following issue:
If a cell on column E, in the interval E5:E70, contains the "N/A" text (without quotes), i want to automatically input the "N/A" text on several specific cells in the same row

Added an image for reference[image]. 
Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks !

Latest edit:
I have attached a copy of the excel, maybe it will be a lot more helpful, for me it just won't work...it's so frustrating...
[excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3BWwyZDViCqY1JYajRQZ3plUDA)

Comment: What's in those cells when they shouldn't show `N/A`?

Comment: usually numbers that i manually input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the code below into the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want to have the action.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim C As Long

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E70")) Is Nothing Then
        SetApplication False
        With Target
            If StrComp(Trim(.Value), "N/A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ' recognises "n/a" as "N/A" and corrects entry
                For C = Columns("E").Column To Columns("AL").Column
                    Cells(.Row, C).Value = "N/A"
                Next C
            End If
        End With
        SetApplication True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetApplication(ByVal AppMode As Boolean)

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = AppMode
        .ScreenUpdating = AppMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've copied the code but it seems that for some reason it does not change any values

Comment: Could be you installed in it the wrong place. It must be in the worksheet's code sheet which is named, like, "Sheet1 (Sheet1)". Could be you misunderstand the functionality. The code will run when you enter "N/A" in any of the cells E5:E70. At all other times it does nothing. In particular, it doesn't look at any existing "N/A" in your worksheet, not even in E5:E70.

Comment: Solved, thank you all for your time and help. Much appreciated !

Comment: Great! Please remember to mark the answer that did the solving. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    For Each cel In ws.Range("E5:E70")
        If CVErr(cel.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
            ws.Range("F" & cel.Row & ":I" & cel.Row) = CVErr(xlErrNA)   'mention desired range instead of (F:I)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assumed (based on the picture) that you want paste N/A's in this way: F - paste, G - don't paste, H - paste - and repeat this three further: paste, don't paste, paste, paste, don't paste, paste, etc.

So this code works accordingly to this rule. You just need to specify very last column instead of `Column.Count - 2` - this bit says just that program should fill until the last column in a sheet.

```
Sub FillNAs()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, j As Long

For i = 5 To 70
    If UCase(Cells(i, 5).Value) = "N/A" Then
        j = 6
        Do While j < Columns.Count - 2
            Cells(i, j).Value = "N/A"
            Cells(i, j + 2).Value = "N/A"
            j = j + 3
        Loop
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```